# Not able to get any response or error while using Spring Websocket STOMP

Tags: spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am using code given in this link : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

When I start my application as spring boot, it starts properly and also the web page is opening on port 8080 but when I click on connect or Send My name to connect then nothing is happening, getting no response anywhere and none error. Please can anyone help me with this

Comment: Hi I am following the same docs example and facing the same issue I removed the cors issue by adding origins but after I got connected to the socket I send the name but not getting any response from the server. Have you resolved that part ? if yes then would you please let me know how you have done that Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You error dispalyed in browser console, you need to check it. In my opinion this problem connected with CORS. Try this:

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {        
         registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

Comment: Hi I followed the same doc and getting the same issue, I resolved that cors issue but I am not getting any response from the server. You having any idea how to resolve it, Thanks